# Screen flashes on launch after saving dark theme to dataStore in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple Light/Dark theme toggle, and I'm saving the theme to a dataStore.
After saving the theme and closing the app, the screen temporarily starts in the light mode before switching to the dark theme. Am I missing something? is it a side-effect thing I'm dealing with here? Please advise.

Here's a GIF explaining the case
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YH7z.gif

---

Here's the code for the theme.kt file

```
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = White100,
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Blue100,
)

@Composable
fun MyTheme(
    darkTheme: MutableState<Boolean>,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit) {

    val colors = if (darkTheme.value) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

---

Here's the code for MainActivity.kt file

```
// DataStore
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("settings")

// DataStore key
val USER_THEME = booleanPreferencesKey("user_theme")

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        // Reading theme
        val themeFlow: Flow<Boolean> = dataStore.data
            .map { preferences ->
                preferences[USER_THEME] ?: false
            }

        // Toggle and save theme
        suspend fun toggleTheme() {
            dataStore.edit { settings ->
                val currentTheme = settings[USER_THEME] ?: false
                settings[USER_THEME] = !currentTheme
            }
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            // Getting the theme from DataStore
            // If the initial value is true, it works fine on dark mode but not on Light
            // If the initial value is false, it works fine on light mode but not on dark
            val userTheme = themeFlow.collectAsState(initial = false)

            // Mutable state of the theme to be passed into "My Theme"
            val themeState: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(userTheme.value)

            // Scope to toggle theme on click
            val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

            // UI
            MyTheme (darkTheme = themeState) {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_dark),
                        contentDescription = "Theme Switcher",
                        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .clickable {
                                scope.launch {
                                    toggleTheme()
                                }
                            }
                    )
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edited code after Francesc's answer:

1. Removed the "userTheme" line and added runBlocking to this line

```
val themeState: MutableState<Boolean> = runBlocking {  mutableStateOf(themeFlow.first())}
```

2. Toggled the theme value manually from the button:

```
scope.launch {
themeState.value = !themeState.value
saveTheme() // renamed it to saveTheme instead of toggleTheme
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theme is read asynchronously from the store and initially it defaults to `false` (not dark theme), so it shows in light mode. Later when the flow emits and the mode is dark, then the UI switches to dark mode.

Due to the asynchronicity of the data store, you have 2 options:

- read the theme initial value synchronously, using `runBlocking`
- display some placeholder while you wait for the read, maybe a `Box` with your app logo (so like a splash screen), or just nothing, a blank canvas